# How to Alter Table column to Collection in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter-table

I want to store value in column of table as list (Nested Table or Table).
How can i do it ?
Thank for your help !
I'm use Oracle Database (PL/SQL) and my IDE is SQL developer.

Comment: Do you specifically need to alter an existing column to make it into a collection, or are you just looking for the [syntax to add a column](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#i2183462) of type [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#i2103531)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below snippet to add nested table column in Oracle table. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type number_ntt
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE TABLE WITH_NESTED_COL
  (
    SR NUMBER,
    NUM_TAB NUMBER_NTT
  )
  nested table NUM_TAB store as NUMBER_TYPE;
```